# Comment section inside each ListBox items

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, listbox

I'm developing an external application in C#/WPF which display information : `Name`, `Details`. Etc...

I handle this part with a ListBox and simple Binding. I populate my ListBox this way :

```
 model.ClassAs.Add(new ClassA { Name = textBox1.Text, Detail = textBox2.Text });
```

The problem come now : I now have to implement a `Comment Section` for users to add comments inside each `ListBoxItems` separately. Obviously I can't fill the `Comment Section` when i populate `Name` and `Details`. So i create a second ListBox inside the `ItemsTemplate` of the first one, a ListBoxSeption if you want. I create an other Class `ClassB` and try to implement the Binding like the first time.

Obviously that did not work because i was in the DataContext of ListBox1. I try to set up an `ObservableCollection` with a `PropertyChanged` Event but i can't get it to work. I don't understand this process very well so i don't see where my error is.

Here is my XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" MouseDoubleClick="ListBox_MouseDoubleClick"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             ItemsSource="{Binding ClassAs, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="1" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid x:Name="grd">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Name="Name" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="DarkGray" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Detail, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                <Grid x:Name="comSection" Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource booleanVisibleConverter}}"
                      Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxCom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                            <controls:WatermarkService.Watermark>
                                <TextBlock>Type Comment Here...</TextBlock>
                            </controls:WatermarkService.Watermark>
                        </TextBox>
                    </AdornerDecorator>
                    <ListBox x:Name="listBoxCom" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                             HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding ClassBs.Commentary}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Name="TBCom" Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Grid>
                <Button x:Name="addComment" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="25" Height="25"
                        BorderThickness="0" Click="addComment_Click" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"
                        ToolTip="Comment">
                    <Button.Content>
                        <Image Source="Assets\plus_orange.png" />
                    </Button.Content>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

What i want : The user fill `textBoxCom` and Press `addComment` Button to add a Comment in the selected ListBoxItem.

My Classes :

```
public sealed class ClassA : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<ClassB> ClassBs { get; set; }
    public List<ClassB> ModifiedComments { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public class ClassB
    {
        string Commentary { get; set;}
    }
}
```

My ViewModel :

```
public sealed class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ClassA> ClassAs { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ClassA.ClassB> ClassBs { get; set; }

    List<ClassA.ClassB> ModifiedItems { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ClassAs = new ObservableCollection<ClassA>();
        CLassBs = new ObservableCollection<ClassA.ClassB>();
        ModifiedItems = new List<ClassA.ClassB>();
        this.ClassBs.CollectionChanged += this.OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (ClassA.ClassB newItem in e.NewItems)
                {
                    ModifiedItems.Add(newItem);

                    //Add listener for each item on PropertyChanged event
                    newItem.PropertyChanged += this.OnItemPropertyChanged;
                }
            }

            if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (ClassA.ClassB oldItem in e.OldItems)
                {
                    ModifiedItems.Add(oldItem);

                    oldItem.PropertyChanged -= this.OnItemPropertyChanged;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("me : " + ex);
        }
        }

    void OnItemPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ClassA.ClassB item = sender as ClassA.ClassB;
        if (item != null)
            ModifiedItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```

My Click Event (AddComment)

```
private void addComment_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        currentSelectedListBoxItem = this.listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(listBox.SelectedIndex) as ListBoxItem;
        System.Windows.Controls.TextBox textBoxCom = Helper.FindDescendant<System.Windows.Controls.TextBox>(currentSelectedListBoxItem);
        ListBox LBCom = Helper.FindDescendant<ListBox>(currentSelectedListBoxItem);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxCom.Text))
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill the Comment Section");
        else
        {
            model.ClassBs.Add(new ClassA.ClassB { Commentary = textBoxCom.Text });
            textBoxCom.Clear();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("exp = " + exp);
    }
}
```

Sorry for the very long post, i hope you can help my on this !

Comment: You don't have to populate the comment property of the class A, but you will still be able to bind it. So that when the user will fill the comment field, your `ClassA` object will hold all of the necessary informations

Comment: Do you mean without using the `PropertyChange` Event ?

Comment: You don't need the `PropertyChanged` event if the bound control is the only one to change the property. This event is used to tell the other objects that would depend on this property that it changed and they might want to refresh/compute again what they did with it

Comment: Ok, so i guess i should have just a list of string in my `ClassA`. But how can i fill this list elements by elements without creating a new `ClassA` each time like so :
`model.ClassAs.Add(new ClassA { Comments = textBoxCom.Text});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was way simpler than expected, i was just digging in useless code!
I get rid of all the code about `ObservableCollection` and `PropertyChange` Event.

My final ClassA Code (no more ClassB) :

```
public sealed class ClassA
{


    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public List<string> Comments { get; set; }

    public Issue()
    {
        Comments = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

And my final Click Event :

```
var selected = listBox.SelectedItem as ClassA;
                selected.Comments.Add(textBoxCom.Text);
                listBox.Items.Refresh();
                textBoxCom.Clear();
```

Thank you @Sidewinder94 !